# django Serializer object has no attribute

Tags: python, django, serialization

I don't have much experience in python but got task to write server in django which will handle api requestes I sent from front part, the thing is that eventho GET works well, POST still throw some errors. If I add new Logo via admin panel, it works, when I try to do so via postman it throw this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 114, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

AttributeError: 'LogoSerializer' object has no attribute 'name'
```

my code:
EDITED

```
class LogoViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Logo.objects.all()
        serializer = LogoSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
def create(self, request):
    serializer = LogoSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        
        bg = LogoSerializer(
            name=serializer.name,
            thumb=serializer.thumb,
            thumbL=serializer.thumbL,
            dataL=serializer.dataL,

            )   
        bg.save()
    else:
        bg = serializer.errors
        # print(bg)

    return Response(bg)
```

and Serializer:

```
class LogoSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Logo
        fields = ('name', 'thumb', 'thumbL', 'dataL')

        def create(self, validated_data):
            return Logo.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't access serializer data via attributes, you access it via the `data` dict.

But there is no need for this at all. Your serializer already contains the code for creating, you should just save it.

```
def create(self, request):
    serializer = LogoSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
         bg = serializer.save()
```

But you don't even need to do this. The ViewSet already does this for you. There is no need to define either `list` or `create` methods on that viewset.

The serializer `create` method is also irrelevant.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, well the thing is that I will need to convert this data a bit before I save it later and that's why I want to assign it a bit more manually. So I set it as you said by ```sequalizer_class.is_valid()``` but then it gives me response ```UnboundLocalError: local variable 'bg' referenced before assignment``` I suppose that serializer_class is just not valid and then it skips whole bg part but I have no idea why it is not valid then...

Comment: You should return `serializer.errors` in that case.

Comment: hmm sorry for bothering again but managed to send file via Postman and still get this ```AttributeError: 'LogoSerializer' object has no attribute 'name'``` error, So before I made mistake and thought that problem is solved because validation skipped that part, but unfortunatelly problem is still there

Comment: Show your new code. You shouldn't be using `serializer.name` at all.

Comment: I edited question with new code, the idea is that now I'm just testing if it works but later response from POST request would need to be polished and put through sort of conversion before assigning it to dataL and save to database

Comment: As I said, inside the `is_valid` you should be doing `serializer.save()`. If you really need to access the individual fields, you would use `serializer.validated_data['name']` etc. All this is explained in the [serializer docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/).

Comment: Works! Ok I got the idea how it works now, thanks for your patience:)